# PHP cURL redirects to another URL

Tags: php, redirect, curl

In my code when I try to fetch redirect using `cURL`, it won't show the new location but when I put the same URL in browser it redirects to somewhere else I don't know how without redirect rules. but I need to get that same URL in result.

Here is the example URL

```
http://www.dailymotion.com/cdn/H264-1280x720/video/x1r819x.mp4?auth=1505704620-2562-a9qmrjvz-6e0f4066eb3a57ce79c011f5c3f932f3
```

Here is the Redirect URL

```
https://proxy-23.sg1.dailymotion.com/video/907/091/106190709_mp4_h264_aac_hd.mp4?auth=1505539349-6658-b3dukan0-a41773a8fa2338e758ce74cff24b0390#cell=sg1&hls_heuristic=1&hls_startFragPrefetch=1
```

Here is my PHP Code

```
$url = "http://www.dailymotion.com/cdn/H264-1280x720/video/x1r819x.mp4?auth=1505704620-2562-a9qmrjvz-6e0f4066eb3a57ce79c011f5c3f932f3";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); // HTTP request is 'HEAD'
$headers=curl_exec($ch);
preg_match_all('/^Location:(.*)$/mi', $headers, $matches);
curl_close($ch);
$print_newurl =  !empty($matches[1]) ? trim($matches[1][0]) : 'http://www.google.com.fr';
echo $print_newurl;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to follow the redirect with `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

**Edit:**

```
$last_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL);
```

If that doesn't work, then try with `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL`. See more http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

Comment: the links only redirects when you put it on the browser and hit enter button

Comment: To me it is just showing `Access to www.dailymotion.com was denied`

Comment: may be because the auth is only allow to my IP

Comment: still not working :( my only requirement to get only dailymotion's CDN url